# How to center a horizontal navigation bar

Tags: css, navigation, centering, menubar

I am having a hard time trying to center the navigation buttons on my website. I have searched and tried different options but havent found any success. Here is what my code looks like. PS - my code is from an elegant theme template.

```
#menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid #f7f7f7;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu #main-menu {
    float: none !important!;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#menu .nav li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px dashed #dcdcdc;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#menu .nav a, ul#mobile_menu a {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #c6c6c6;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    height: 44px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in;
}

#menu .nav a > span {
    padding: 12px 14px 11px;
}

#menu .nav ul li a > span {
    padding: 0;
}

#menu .nav ul li {
    border: none;
}

#menu .nav ul a, ul#mobile_menu a {
    padding: 14px 5px 14px 25px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 195px;
}

#menu .nav ul a:hover, ul#mobile_menu a:hover {
    background: #4b93ad;
    text-decoration: none;
}

span.menu_slide {
    color: #fff;
    background: #549eb9;
}

ul#mobile_menu a {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: auto;
}

#menu .nav > li.current_page_item > a:hover {
    background: none;
    color: #c6c6c6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `#menu {margin: 0 auto;}`

OR

```
#menu {
float: left;
text-align: center;
}

#menu ul {
display: inline-block;
}
```

If you provide a link I can look at it for you.